# Regex to match everything (including new lines) between keywords

Tags: regex, vbscript, newline

I am writing a vbscript file to parse data out of a log file.
Log file has this structure in it, always formatted this certain way:

```
<name="ExecResponse" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXX==" />
```

How can I just match the data in between the quotes (XXXXX), even with 0 or more new lines?
Not language specific, but I am validating in Textpad, so not sure if global operators are available to me, but in VBScript they are.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html

Comment: @CodeJockey: That won't work (at least not in VBScript); ECMAScript doesn't have a DOTALL modifier.

Comment: That is what that page says - it also suggests an alternative of `[\s\S]`, which I've used - This is why I've put it in a comment instead of an answer; also because you've suggested an alternative, and I'm burping a baby. FINAL EDIT - it's the second link on Google when you search for "VBScript regex newline"

Comment: @CodeJockey: Oops. I just read "dot" in the link and failed to check the page. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBScript solution, since you tagged your question [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript):

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
txt = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\your.log").ReadAll

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = """([^""]*)"""
re.Global = True

For Each m In re.Execute(txt)
  WScript.Echo m.SubMatches(0)
Next
```

Demonstration:

```
>>> s = "<name=""ExecResponse"" value=""XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" & vbNewLine & _
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" & vbNewLine & _
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" & vbNewLine & _
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" & vbNewLine & _
"XXXXXXXXXXXXX=="" />"
>>> WScript.Echo s
<name="ExecResponse" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXX==" />
>>> Set re = New RegExp
>>> re.Pattern = """([^""]*)"""
>>> re.Global = True
>>> For Each m In re.Execute(s) : WScript.Echo m.SubMatches(0) : Next
ExecResponse
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXX==
```

The actual regular expression is `"([^"]*)"`, but the double quotes must be doubled to escape them inside the string.

If you want a more specific match (e.g. just the value of the `value` attribute), you need to make the regular expression more specific, e.g. like this: `value="([^"]*)"`.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use `/"[^"]*"/g`, assuming that all quotes are correctly balanced, and none are escaped.

Comment: I tried this and it matched: 'ExecResponse', " value=", and so on... but not the data (XXX's)

Comment: @Chinobling: Well, `ExecResponse` is between quotes, too, so I assumed you wanted to match that as well. It doesn't match `" value:"`, though, since every character can only be matched once (see http://regex101.com/r/jD6cJ6). If you want to restrict the match to those that are preceded by `value=`, just use `/value="([^"]*)"/g` and grab the contents of group 1.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
value\="([^"]*)"
```

Or this if you want to allow possible spaces:

```
value[[:space:]]?\=[[:space:]]?"([^"]*)"
```

**In theory, the word value followed by an escaped equals sign followed by a quote, followed by anything that's not a quote, followed by another quote.**

I'm not familiar with VB script but the 'anything but a quote' part should also include new lines.  Note in other languages there are switches to include new lines.

Ex PHP uses the /s modifier for new lines:

```
<?php
preg_match('/value\="([^"]*)"/s',$string);
?>
```